# how to fix an index out of range error and instead print a statement

Tags: python

I have an assignment to create a program where a user guesses a random 5 digit number. What i have works except for one part. When a user enters a number that is longer than 5 digits its just supposed to print this is too long and move on to the next try. For what i have it instead prints the error and stops the game. Is there away that i can fix this?

```
while not userguess:
    uniquedigits_found = 0
    tries += 1
    guess = str(input("Enter your 5 digit attempt: "))
    if len(guess) < 5:
        print("this is too short")
    elif len(guess) > 5:
        print("this is too long")
```

Comment: Sounds like your `uniqueDigitsFound` has a bug.

Comment: Prob. better to share all complete functions.

Comment: What is a "collections error"? Please show the exact error message including traceback.

Comment: the error says this     collections.literable got 'int' instead

Comment: the other functions are added

Comment: This code is incomplete. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ok the other half is added

Comment: @Alz You still haven't made a [mcve]. If anyone tries to run you code they will receive the error `NameError: name 'userguess' is not defined`, and not be able to run it at all.

Comment: @John Coleman sorry didnt notice it should be there now

Comment: Much better -- perhaps you can also fix that stray `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple: just add two `continue` statements:

```
if len(guess) < 5:
        print("this is too short")
        continue
    elif len(guess) > 5:
        print("this is too long")
        continue
```

These will cause execution to instantly continue on to the next pass through the while loop, skipping over the code that triggers the index error.